# Best way to replace image buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery

Below I have an image button:

```
<table id="question">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<a onclick="return plusbutton();">
<img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" id="mainPlusbutton" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
</a>
<span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look up Previous Questions)</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now what I want to do is by using jquery I want to hide the current image `Images/plussign.jpg` and replace with another image `Images/plussigndisabled.jpg` in the if statement below:

```
if (qnum == <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {

}
```

And then in the document ready function I want it to replace the `Images/plussigndisabled.jpg` with `Images/plussign.jpg`

I want to know what is the best way to achieve this in jquery?

UPDATE:

Below is what I tried:

```
var x = "<img src='Images/plussigndisabled.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='plusimage' name='plusbuttonrow'/><span id='plussignmsg'>(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>" ;

    if (qnum == <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {


     $('#plus th').html($(x)); 

        $("#showGridId").unbind('click').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }).css('color', '#BBBBBB');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: so you want to take a decision using this if condition on php side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it all in PHP :

```
$imgsrc = "Images/plussign.jpg";
if (qnum == $_SESSION['textQuestion']) {
   $imgsrc = "Images/plussigndisabled.jpg";
}
```

Then output the image like so :

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgsrc ?>"
```

You cannot access PHP variables in JavaScript and you cannot access JavaScript variables in PHP ... and I don't see the point of casting if you stored the variable in the session in the first instance !

### Update

Not really sure why you are doing this ... but try something like :

```
var x = "<img src='Images/plussigndisabled.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='plusimage' name='plusbuttonrow'/><span id='plussignmsg'>(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>";

if (qnum == <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {

   $('#plus th').html(x); // no need to create a jQuery object

   $("#showGridId").unbind('click').click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }).css('color', '#BBBBBB');
}
```

Comment: It is an actual jquery function this if statement is in, I am just using the php to get the question number but I really want it done in jquery, but you answer is good for people who may just want to use php to do this. Can you please look at my update to see what I have attempted in jquery

Comment: Guessing you are right, why am I doing it this way even if your attempt doesn't work. What Im trying to do is replace the image button but I don't want the click function for the image button to work thats why I have done it this way, but Im messing something up